# When I try to generate files for protobuf I get error ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

When I try to generate files with the command

`python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I./ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. service.proto`

I get error.

```
Traceback:
test_client.py:11: in <module>
    from tests.remote.grpc_wrapper.service_pb2_grpc import TestServiceServicer, add_TestServiceServicer_to_server, \
service_pb2_grpc.py:4: in <module>
    import service_pb2 as service__pb2
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'service_pb2'
```

How can I fix it? I truing reinstall protobuf but it don’t help me.

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip install -U protobuf
```

P.S. I use conda, I truing use

```
conda install protobuf
```

but it don’t help me too.

[image]

Comment: your error is here `service_pb2`  no module . install it

Comment: @prashantrana, `service_pb2` is OP's filename. It's not a lib. @user45245, from which folder are you trying to run the python command, `python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I./ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. service.proto`

Comment: (venv) C:\Users\Valentin\PycharmProjects\protoactor-python\tests\remote\grpc_wrapper>python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I./ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. service.proto

Comment: I have found a solution. Use "from . import" in _pb2_grpc.py for example from . import service_pb2 as service__pb2

Answer (score 10):

There's talk of specifying this at the point of generation in the .proto file in [this issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/1491). As far as I know you have two options currently:

1) Change your line 4 to have `.` in front (this signifies a relative import):

```
from . import service_pb2 as service__pb2
```

2) Change the `__init__.py` file in the "grpc_wrapper" folder to include:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Comment: here's a shell command to replace it the package name - $target - with proper syntanx (e.g. in github action)
`find $REPOPATH/$reponame/ -type f -name "*.py" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's, import '"$target"'_pb2, from . import '"$target"'_pb2, g'`