# Getting imports right using grpc

Tags: python, import, grpc, init

I know, this question was probably asked a lot. I consider myself a newbie on Python and sometimes I don't quite get how the importing system works. Especially in my case I have not found any solutions without a workaround I don't want to do. Why? Let me explain:

So I have this "program" which works with Google protobufs. When creating Python code from the given compiler (protoc) it always says "DO NOT EDIT!". So I don't edit the generated code and I don't really want to (There must be a solution without fixing each file by myself every time the code is generated).

Here is how my project is organized:

```
|root:
|---protos:
|   |---API:
|   |   |---protoApiA.proto
|   |   |---protoApiB.proto ...
|   |---common:
|       |---protoCommonA.proto ...
|---src:
|   |---__init__.py
|   |---foo:
|   |   |---__init__.py
|   |   |---bar:
|   |   |   |---main.py
|   |   |   |---protos:
|   |   |   |   |---API:
|   |   |   |   |   |---protoApiA_pb2.py
|   |   |   |   |   |---protoApiB_pb2-grpc.py ...
|   |   |   |   |---common:
|   |   |   |   |   |---protoCommonA_pb2.py
|   |   |   |   |   |---....
|---test_script.py
```

protoApiA.proto imports from protoCommonA.proto.

```
import "common/protoCommonA.proto";
```

Which resolves into:

```
from common import protoCommonA_pb2 as common_dot_protoCommonA__pb2
```

After I created them using following PowerShell prompt:

```
& py -3.10 -m grpc_tools.protoc -I./protos --python_out=./src/foo/bar/protos/ --grpc_python_out=./src/foo/bar/protos/ common/protoCommonA.proto API/protoApiA.proto API/protoApiB.proto
```

So far so good. Here is what the init files contain:

```
# root/src/__init__.py:
from . import foo

# root/src/foo/__init__.py:
from .bar.main import ... #relevant functions for test_script.py
```

The file main.py needs to use the proto files for some gRPC related stuff.
The file test_script.py is a script which uses some functionalities from main.py mainly for testing.

If I test the functionality over test_script.py it throws a "module not found"-error at protoApiA_pb2.py since it does not know about protoCommonA_pb2.py.

So here is my question:
How can I make this work, without editing the import statements in any of the automatically generated Python files?

I informed myself about how the import system works, but I think I do not understand how it really works, since I can't come up with any solution trying the last three days.

Thanks in advance! And hopefully someone can explain to me why I have this issue and how to properly resolve it

Comment: Regrettably, the simplest solution is to generate the Python stubs into the working directory and reference them from there. This obviates needing to edit dot not edit files. See [this](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/1491) long-standing issue. This Stackoverflow [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61637430/) provides a good overview of the problem and some solutions. Generally (!) protobuf schemas define a 3rd-party's API, generating the code into standalone repos|packages to reflect this is a good solution.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you! Definitly looking into this. I've seen some issues (nearly same as mine) from like 2016 never resolved or reopened in 2020-2023. It seems like a common problem. On top, the protobuf files I have are delivered by a company and thus I don't want to reorder their structure bacause they often update these files and every time they update them, I have to check and reorder them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, I found myself editing the generated proto files automatically right after their creation with a small script.

Although Google uses Protobufs extensively (obviously), they have a flat hierarchy inside their packages or install their proto packages separately. Thus, they do not encounter these problems, and a fix is most likely not made (The issue has persisted since ~2015).